# how to use the word imperative?

Tags: word-choice

how to use the word imperative when referring to plural and not singular?
the above mentioned issues are imperative to the growth of the economy
or 
the above mentioned issues are imperatives to the growth of the economy

Comment: Use "imperative" not "imperatives." It doesn't matter that "issues" is plural. As Edwin says below, "imperative" is an adjective. If you add the S to the end of the word "imperative," then the word is a plural noun, which is actually grammatically correct but changes the meaning of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

The adjectival usage of 'imperative' is probably more common than the count noun usage. This is what is being used in

> It is imperative that we destroy the bridge.
>
> It is imperative to the Allied advance.
>
> It is imperative to destroy it.

Compare

> It is important to her.
>
> It is essential to have air cover.

Comment: Given OP specifically mentions singular/plural, I think we should assume he's asking about the *noun* usage, in which case plural *issues are* requires plural ***imperatives***. Personally, I'd prefer the preposition *imperatives **for*** rather than ***to*** before the [desired] outcome, but both are in common use.